# Big Csv file into DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, upload, insert

My CSV has a size of 4gb and I need to import it into SQL server.
I think it has more then 20 million rows. If some one could get me a method to do this in less then an hour I would be very thankful.

What I'm already doing:

```
using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8)) {

            string line = "";
            bool isHeader = true;
            int counter = 0;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {

                if (isHeader) {
                    model.Columns = line.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    isHeader = false;
                    continue;
                } else {

                    if (Settings.Default.RonudSet != 0) {
                         LoadInDB(indicator,RoundDecimals(line));
                    } else {
                        LoadInDB(indicator, line);  
                    }
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                counter++;
            }
 }
            model.RowCount = counter;
            model.ColumnsCount = model.Columns.Length;
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

My Db upload method:

```
public void LoadInDB(char indicator, string key) {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.DBconnection)) {

            conn.Open();
            try {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.LipperFilesTestingInsertFileRowKey", conn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileRowKey", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100));
                cmd.Parameters["@FileRowKey"].Value = key;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@targetTableIndicator", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100));
                cmd.Parameters["@targetTableIndicator"].Value = indicator;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            } catch (SqlException sqlExc) {

                MyLog.WriteToLog(sqlExc.Message,MyLog.Messages.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not be opening a new connection every time you insert a row. That will destroy your performance. Open the connection before beginning to read the file and close it at the end.
2. Use transactions. Search for `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction`. This will improve the performance on the DB-side. Without transactions, SQL Server will be committing each insert, which is a waste.
3. Consider scrapping this entire method of loading data, and instead use SQL Server's `BULK INSERT` abilities.

Comment: Additionally it is possible to upload data via dataset and dataadapter. What usually slows down individual updates is the wait time for log flush and you need to account for that. The easiest solution is to simply batch commit. Eg. commit every 1000 inserts, or every second. This will fill up the log pages and will amortize the cost ow log flush wait over all the inserts in a transaction. As with any performance test, make sure you eliminate randomness, and preallocate the database and the log, you don't want to hit db or log growth event.